# ¿Como crear una funcion de datos estadisticos en rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
rm(list=ls(all=T))#limpia todo lo antes escrito

library(tuneR) #libreria para manipular archivos de audio

library(e1071)#libreria para sacar la skewness y kurtosis

directorio<-"/home/roy/Descargas/audios"   #variable donde se almacena el directorio

ld <- list.dirs(directorio, recursive = FALSE)# Se abre el directorio principal


#se inicialisa la variable deacuerto a lo que el usario desee fracmentar el audio
tiempo_de_inicio<-50000
duracion<-tiempo_de_inicio 
cons<-duracion

w<-1
k<-1
fi<-""
inicio<-0

Nombre<-""
Media<-""
Mediana<-""
Moda<-""
Skewness<-""
Kurtosis<-""
z<-""
xy<-""
pk<-""

####################################### FUNCION MODA #########################################

Mode <- function(x) {
ux <- unique(x)
ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

################################ FUNCION PDF #########################################
graficas_pdf= function (parte,i,j,w){ #funcion que sirve para generar los   graficos en pdf

nombre<-paste(i,'/',j,"_",w,".pdf",sep = "")
pdf(file =nombre)
plot(parte)  
dev.off()  

}
   ###########################################################################


for (i in ld) {            # Se recoren las subcarpetas

  lf <- list.files(i)        # se en lista lo que alla en ellas 

    for (j in lf) {               #se recorren los archivos 

     dire<-i
     setwd(dire)                #se fija el nuevo directorio
     cat('Directorio', i, 'archivo', j, '\n') 

     pista<-readWave(j)                 #se lee el archivo .wave
     canalizq<- mono(pista, "left")      #se extrae el canal izquierdo


     frecuencia=pista@samp.rate            #se saca la frecuencia en la que esta el audio

       if(frecuencia==44100){                # busca en que frecuencia se encuentra el audio #frecuencia de 44100 repeticiones por segundo 

         duracion<-tiempo_de_inicio*4        #incrementa las variables dependiendo de la frecuencia
         cons<-duracion

         submuestreo<- downsample(canalizq,frecuencia)   #se extrae el canadel dependiendo de la frecuencia


          for(y in 1:length(submuestreo)){              #se recorre el canal extraido

            if(duracion<=length(submuestreo)) { 
            #Se extraen los fracmentos de acuerdo al tamaño que el usuario dio

             parte<- extractWave(submuestreo,from = inicio, to =duracion,xunit =c("samples", "time"))  #se extrae el espectro

             graficas_pdf(parte,i,j,w)                  #se aplica la funcion para guardar en pdf


               x=parte@left                        #se extrae la parte izquierda del espectro para sacar los datos estadisticos


               Media[k]<-mean(x)

               Mediana[k]<- median(x)

               Moda[k]<-Mode(x)

               Skewness[k]<-skewness(x)

               Kurtosis[k]<-kurtosis(x) ##latex

               Nombre[k]<-paste(j,"_",w,".pdf",sep = "")


               df<- data.frame( Nombre,Media, Mediana, Moda, Skewness,Kurtosis )

               inicio=inicio+cons                         
               duracion=duracion+cons

               w=w+1

        }else if(duracion>length(submuestreo)){            

        print("El audio es menos al fracmento que se pide")
        break;
      }
      k=k+1

    }


    inicio=0          
    duracion<-tiempo_de_inicio
    w=1


  }


  direc<-paste(directorio,"/Datos_Estadisticos.csv",sep = "") #se le pasa el directorio y se aumente el nombre del archivo

  write.csv(df,file=direc) #se crea el archivo que contendra los datos estadisticos


 }
```

lo que el codigo genera es:

Todo el codigo funciona a la perfección, la funcion de este programa es tomar unos audios que estan en la ruta  Descargas/audios luego los procesa y extrae el canal izquierdo con el cual se generan sus espectros por medio de pdf y saca los datos estadisticos, guardandolos en un archivo .csv. la cuestion es que en la parte del codigo donde se sacan los datos estadicos ---->

```
        Media[k]<-mean(x)

        Mediana[k]<- median(x)

        Moda[k]<-Mode(x)

        Skewness[k]<-skewness(x)

        Kurtosis[k]<-kurtosis(x) ##latex

        Nombre[k]<-paste(j,"_",w,".pdf",sep = "")


        df     <- data.frame( Nombre,Media, Mediana, Moda, Skewness,Kurtosis )
```

como hacer para que ese código poderlo convertirlo a un a función y luego solo llamar la función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para encapsular una porción de código en una función, en primer lugar hay que definir cuál va a ser el input y cuál el output esperado. Viendo un poco tu código, veo que el input debiera ser:

- `x`: los datos, seguramente un vector, lo llamaremos `data`.
- `j`: entiendo que es el nombre de un archivo, lo llamaremos `fname`
- `w`: pareciera ser un contador, lo llamaremos `nfile`

La salida, por lo que se ve del código debiera ser una fila de un `data.frame` que tendremos que ir agregándola a un `data.frame` general.

Veamos como definiríamos la rutina:

```
get_data <- function(data, fname, nfile) {
    return(data.frame(Media = mean(data),
                      Mediana = median(data),         
                      Moda = Mode(data),         
                      Skewness = skewness(data),         
                      Kurtosis = kurtosis(data),         
                      Nombre = paste(fname,"_",nfile,".pdf",sep = "")
    ))
}
```

Para usarla:

```
# Antes que nada, afuera de todos los ciclos 
# tenemos que inicializar la variable df como un data.frame vacio
df <- data.frame() 

# Ahora sí dentro del ciclo, agregamos cada "fila" de datos obtenidas
# al data.frame general
df <- rbind(df, get_data(x, j, w))
```

Algunos comentarios:

- En general tengo el criterio que las funciones no tengan acceso a variables globales, pero lo cierto es que también podríamos pasar `df` por parámetro y que sea la misma función la que invoque a `rbind()` y vaya agregando las filas.
- Si la función la vamos a compartir siempre es bueno incorporar un `requiere(library)` para indicar los paquetes adicionales que requiere para funcionar y poder cargarlos, lo digo por las funciones no estándar `skewness` y `kurtosis`.
- Como puedes observar, eliminamos la necesidad de las matrices intermedias: `Nombre`, `Media`, `Mediana`, `Moda`, `Skewness` y `Kurtosis`, lo cual simplifica bastante el código.

Comment: ola antes que nada muchas gracias por responder. fue de mucha ayuda su respuesta. eso era lo que andaba buscando muchas gracias